# Latex code error when I want to build

Tags: miktex

What is this error? Could not start the command : "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "azam1".tex

C:\Users\a>pdflatex-version 'pdflatex-version' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Can you please open `cmd.ext`, input `pdflatex -version` (note the space character just before `-version`), press "Enter" key to run, and add what it outputs to your question description?

Comment: C:\Users\a>pdflatex-version
'pdflatex-version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Then this falls into a MiKTeX installation problem. I'm not on Windows so I might not provide most useful help. Have to tried to restart the computer? Reinstall the MiKTeX?